# How to pass System.Net.ICredentials to API?

Tags: c#

First, credentials are given for authentication with said API:

```
Webservice.Authenticate.Credential credential = new Webservice.Authenticate.Credential
{
    Username = "myUserName",
    Password = GetMD5("myPassword"), // See below for a MD5 encoding example method
    ApplicationId = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"), //YOUR ID HERE
    IdentityId = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") //Default is empty guid (no need to edit this)
};
```

If I try to directly utilize the credentials as Icredentials, like so `_service.Credentials = credential;` the following error occurs:

Cannot implicitly convert type auth.credential to system.net.icredentials. I attempted to cast it, but it did not work correctly.

Later, I tried to utilize the credentials in this manner when another service is called. However, I am unsure of how to pass the credentials.

```
TransactionService.TransactionService _service = new TransactionService.TransactionService();
TransactionService.TransactionSearchParameters _params = new TransactionService.TransactionSearchParameters();
_service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(credential.Username, credential.Password);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[System.Net.ICredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.icredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a collection.

Try:

```
_service.Credentials.Add("uri:my.uri"
   , "authenticationType"
   , new NetworkCredential(credential.Username, credential.Password)
);
```